# UI Intensive Application

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, controls, dispatcher

In my program, there is a map editor, after loading the information from the database, I need to generate some custom controls (6000-10000 depending on the map). Unfortunately it locks the user's screen for 10-20 seconds.

How can I do using lazy loading? How can I do without crash and lock screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is much to broad. But i can give you a number of hints.
First of all i'am pretty sure you don't need so many custom controls. Think about how many input devices the user has, he can't interact with that many controls **at the same time**. So you can "cheat" about these controls in a couple of different ways. For example, display an image of the control, and switch it if the user starts to interact with it. 
Another thing is, you don't need what you don't see. Why create a list of 10000 Elements if only 10 will fit on the screen? There is no reason, thats why there are ways to mitigate that, one is called [Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx#Controls) which can be done in a number of ways. You can use UI Virtualization, by defer the loading of the ui components or use data virtualization.
Another thing, in cooperation with data virtualization is to use threads or a background worker to handle the load of that much data. Create your data in batches to give the UI Thread time to handle the windows messages.

Comment: Most of these controls have images and are all within a canvas..
Shown is a map on the screen, unfortunately you have to see the whole map, but as you said, maybe I can remove other information that he certainly did not use, or attempt some form of virtualization.

Comment: You only have a certain amount of pixels, you can and usually must always fake and cheat when displaying data to the user. Look into googlemaps for example, they don't have one gigantic image, they cleverly reload and cache. Things like that might be a way for you too.

Comment: I found the big problem in my application. Encapsulate a canvas inside another canvas, recursively.. It really is very heavy, I'm changing the operation..

Answer (score 1):

Look into Binding or doing the work in a Background thread?
If they are in a ListView, look into VirtualMode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx

What are you loading these controls into? Are you doing it in the UI thread?

Comment: Most of these controls have images and are all within a canvas, unfortunately I can not use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use TPL (Task Parallel Library) to do the DB tasks on a separate thread... it looks like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyLongRunningMethod));
```

Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) great article over on CodeProject for more information...

EDIT: As noted below the original answer implied that somehow controls can be generated on a separate thread but in reality as a part of the visual tree and therefore the UI, controls must be generated on the UI thread so that was not a valid suggestion...

EDIT: Don't see how it would be possible to fit 10000 custom controls on a signle screen so there must be a way to use some type of virtualization schema where only visible controls would get generated and the rest of the controls would get generated on demand...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a way to use tasks to create and manage the visual components...

Comment: You're right, controls are a part of the UI and thus must be generated on the UI thread... will modify the answer to that effect...